# Are app-scoped user IDs supposed to stay the same across logins?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A dev who is working with us is logging into our Facebook App and it seems like every time they are logging in, they get a different user-id (app scoped user id).

Is this expected behavior? Under what circumstances should this happen?

Comment: No, this is not expected behavior, and should happen under no circumstances. Are you sure they are using the same account every time (and aren’t one of the numbskulls who create multiple user profiles, and then are surprised if Facebook blocks those accounts upon discovery), and that they are logging into the very same app (same app id, or a test version of an existing app) …?

Comment: How do you get the ID?

Comment: I am sure, mainly because each of the IDs redirects *to the same profile*.